# Como inserir dados no mysql via ajax + php + foundation 5

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, banco-de-dados, zurb-foundation

Queria saber como posso inserir dados no MySQL via Ajax + PHP utilizando o Framework Zurb Foundation 5? A propriedade "data-reveal-ajax" do framework já substitui uma função Ajax de inserção?

Answer (score 0):

O `data-reveal-ajax` funciona simplesmente para abrir um modal com conteúdo de uma url ou uma pagina que faz alguma requisição ele por si só não é capaz de fazer requisições Ajax.

Comment: Minha intenção é justamente inserir dados no mysql através do modal do Foundation 5. Então seria o caso criar uma função ajax?

Comment: Com toda certeza meu caro, crie a função.